# I want to see if the ratio of cats to dogs is increasing from 1995 to 1996. how would I frame the null hypothesis?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, bootstrap

Suppose I have this data set (I'm making it up) about a cat and dog shelter

```
Animal ID      Animal type       Birth Year

100              Cat              1997

101              Dog              1995

103              Cat              1997

104              Dog              1992

...              ...              ...
```

I want to see if the ratio of cats to dogs is increasing from 1995 to 1996. how would I frame the null hypothesis? and what could be some tests on r i could use to solve this problem?

I'm new to R, so any approaches are welcomed

Comment: This is a two-sample proportion test. Search that term. Briefly, “prop.test” will do what you’re looking for by testing the null hypothesis that the proportion of dogs is the same in 1995 and 1996, against the usual types of alternative hypotheses: greater than, less than, not equal.